# cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Windows.Sdk.DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE' to 'uint'

Tags: c#, winapi, windows-11

**The following only works/can be tested on Win11**

---

Hello, I am trying to edit the TitleBar color in my WPF app...

It throws me this error with the following code using CSWIN32 on .net5 and `dotnet build`:

```cs
using Microsoft.Windows.Sdk;

[...]

private static void SetTitleBarColor(HWND hwnd)
{
    unsafe
    {
        const uint DWMWA_CAPTION_COLOR = 35;

        // 0x002b36  RGB (solarized-base03)
        WInterop.Gdi.Native.COLORREF colorRef = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0x00, 0x2b, 0x36);
        HRESULT setBgResult = PInvoke.DwmSetWindowAttribute(hwnd, (DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE)DWMWA_CAPTION_COLOR, &colorRef, 4);
                
    }
}
```

The code works and throws no errors apart from the one above, it is from [MaximalWebView](https://github.com/rgwood/MaximalWebView/blob/1122ceb4951f42129f03214bdd4c6e3a52613ddf/MaximalWebView/Program.cs#L297) and the base/WPF codebase is from the [CsWin32 WPF Workaround](https://github.com/microsoft/CsWin32/issues/7)

> error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.Windows.Sdk.DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE' to 'uint'

Comment: What happens if you take out the `(DWMWINDOWATTRIBUTE)` ?

Comment: Like the [metadata](https://github.com/microsoft/win32metadata) that it's sourced from, [CsWin32](https://github.com/microsoft/cswin32) is highly volatile. You're going to have to state the version you are using, and - ideally - post the generated P/Invoke signature.

Comment: In all likeliness, though, you should probably just remove the cast as well as the constant definition. `DWMWA_CAPTION_COLOR` is part included in the metadata. If it doesn't surface in CsWin32, file an issue with that repository.